# How to upgrade android java project

Tags: java, android-studio

I've an old android project (Java) which was made around 5 years ago by another java developer and now i need to upgrade this project but i am a web developer so i can't deal with java project.
I can build it with android studio v4.2.2 but i receive Notes:

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

and some functions not work on real device (The app crashes and close)

My question is how to upgrade this project and make sure its not used a deprecated API?

I am ready for any clarification or code sending.

MichaelAttendanceApp.java :

```
package com.michael.attendanceapp;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MichaelAttendanceApp extends Activity {
//  /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    static final String ACTION_SCAN = "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN";
    private final Class_GetData GD = new Class_GetData();
    private final Class_ArrangeCall arrange = new Class_ArrangeCall();
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String [][] AttendanceData;
    private AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mTask;
    String reply ="";
    int AttendanceRowsCount = 0;
    
    
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }



    public void scanQR(View v) {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            showDialog(MichaelAttendanceApp.this, "No Scanner Found", "Download a scanner code activity?", "Yes", "No").show();
        }
    }
    
    
    public void syncAttendance(View v) {
        try
        {
//      /** Retrieving data from database **/
        //use cursor to keep all data
        //cursor can keep data of any data type
         AttendanceData=GD.GetAttendance(MichaelAttendanceApp.this);
         AttendanceRowsCount = AttendanceData.length;

         if (AttendanceRowsCount > 0)
         {
             mTask = new GetDataFromServer().execute();
         }else
         {
             Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "No records found ..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
             toast.show();
         }
        
        
//      /** show confirmation toast **/
        //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Synchronization Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        //toast.show();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    
     private class GetDataFromServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
         
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Showing progress dialog
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MichaelAttendanceApp.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }
     
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                for(int i =0;i<AttendanceData.length;i++)
                {
                    
                        
                        String param3 = AttendanceData[i][0] + "/"+(AttendanceData[i][1]).toString().replace(" ", "%20")+"/"+AttendanceData[i][2]+"/"+AttendanceData[i][3]+"/"+AttendanceData[i][4];
                         reply = arrange.ArrangeCall("scan_qr", 1, param3, MichaelAttendanceApp.this);
                        if (reply.equals(""))
                        {
                            GD.UpdateAttendance(MichaelAttendanceApp.this, Integer.parseInt(AttendanceData[i][0]), AttendanceData[i][1], AttendanceData[i][2], AttendanceData[i][3], AttendanceData[i][4]);
                        }else
                        {
                           break;
                            
                        }
                }
                return null;
            }
     
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                // Dismiss the progress dialog
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                GD.DeleteAttendance(MichaelAttendanceApp.this);
               
                if(reply.equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MichaelAttendanceApp.this,"Upload Done" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else
                {
                     Toast.makeText(MichaelAttendanceApp.this,reply , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                    
                }
            }
    

    private static AlertDialog showDialog(final Activity act, CharSequence title, CharSequence message, CharSequence buttonYes, CharSequence buttonNo) {
        AlertDialog.Builder downloadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
        downloadDialog.setTitle(title);
        downloadDialog.setMessage(message);
        downloadDialog.setPositiveButton(buttonYes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:" + "com.google.zxing.client.android");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                try {
                    act.startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

                }
            }
        });
        downloadDialog.setNegativeButton(buttonNo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            }
        });
        return downloadDialog.show();
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String memID = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
//              /** String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT"); **/

//              /** get current time and the day of week **/
                Calendar cc = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
                String currTime = sdf.format(cc.getTime());
                
//              /** get the day of the week number **/
                int day = cc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                
                
//              /** convert the number of the day to the day name **/
                String dayName = "";
                 if(day == 2){
                        dayName = "Mon";
                    } else if (day==3){
                        dayName = "Tue";
                    } else if (day==4){
                        dayName = "Wed";
                    } else if (day==5){
                        dayName = "Thu";
                    } else if (day==6){
                        dayName = "Fri";
                    } else if (day==7){
                        dayName = "Sat";
                    } else if (day==1){
                        dayName = "Sun";
                    }
                
                
                 //get Member ID from the URl [last 6 char]
                 //int URLLenght = memID.length();
                 
                 //for ma7abawy
                 //int ID=Integer.parseInt(memID.substring(URLLenght-6, URLLenght));
                 int ID=Integer.parseInt(memID);
                 
                    int mYear = cc.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    int mMonth = cc.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
                    int mDay = cc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                //textView.setText(""+mDay+"/"+mMonth+"/"+mYear);
                 
                 String Sdate = ""+mYear+"-"+mMonth+"-"+mDay;
                 
                 String Activity = "Ma7abawy";
                 //for MASA
//                insert data into able **/
               GD.InsertAttendance(MichaelAttendanceApp.this,ID, currTime, dayName, Sdate, Activity);
                
//              show confirmation toast
//              Toast toastt = Toast.makeText(this, Sdate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
//              toastt.show();
               
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
                
//              /** return to scanning activity **/
                this.scanQR(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It crashes Here : `public void onActivityResult`

Answer (score 0):

The note is very unlikely to be the cause of the error.

For instance using a `List` without generic type causes it.

```
List strings = new ArrayList();
```

vs

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList();
```

In that particular case adding the `<String>` part will be enough for the note to disappear, but your code will still fail.

You're going to have to debug the app to know the cause of the crashes.

Comment: So is there a way to totally upgrade the whole project ?

Comment: Not automatically. Press F2 on each file and will take you to the next error/warning.  Alt + Enter will suggest a fix, but you have to know what you're doing. Many of the fixes are not really a problem, e.g. `return a  == false` might be suggested to change to `return !a;`

Comment: can i show you some code to check and help me ?

Comment: Fixing the warnings is unlikely to help. You are going to have to learn how to get a stack trace from an Android app (I don't know how to do that) and how to attach a debugger.

Comment: @MichaelMagdy Sure, but I can tell you already the best course  of  action is to have someone who knows Android programming to take a look at the code. It would be nearly impossible to debug your code from a text you can post here vs. having the actual Android studio open and add logs / run debugger etc.